# Trying to make a simple falling ball program

Tags: java, physics, particles

This is what I have so far.  It tells me that I have a syntax error on the lines marked below, saying that it expected a "{" and a "}" respectively, without the double quotes around them.  Any suggestions?

```
public class attempt1 {
//use Euler-Richardson algorithm

//defining the initial conditions
double v0=30;
double theta=40;
double x0=0;
double y0=0;

double v0x=v0*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(theta));
double v0y=v0*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(theta));
double dt= .01;
double ax=0;
double ay=-9.8;

double x=0;
double y=0; //this line here, on the semi-colon
while (y>=0) {
    double vx= v0x+1/2*ax*dt;
    double vy= v0y+1/2*ay*dt;   

    double x= x0+1/2*vx*dt;
    double y= y0+1/2*vy*dt;

        if (y<=0){System.out.println(x);}
}
} //and right over here, on the brace itself
```

Comment: You can't put statements outside any method (or constructor or initializer).

Comment: sorry, I'm pretty new at coding (about maybe 2 weeks in, haha).  Where exactly are you referring to?

Comment: You need to put the while loop in a method - something that maybe looks like `public static void main(String[] args) { /* while loop here */ }`

Comment: Ahh, yes, I just tried this.  It seems to have solved my problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to run statements inside a class body. They should be in a method. like this:

```
public class Attempt1{
    private void doSomething(){
        //example code
        int a = 1 + 1;
        while (a < 2) {
            //do random stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Right now you have something similar to this:

```
public class Attempt1 {
    //while{...}    <---- WRONG!
}
```

Statements should be in a method (sometimes called function) at all times. 
You can however put variables outside a method. This will make them accessible for all methods in that class.

You should check out some starting tutorials like the one Oracle gives:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/

Comment: *"They should be in a function"* <cough>method<cough>

Comment: Yes, I just tried this.  This solved my problem, thanks!

Comment: @MadProgrammer Method and functions are often used together. You will find both names for the same things. If it is good or not, everyone will understand :) as you can see i also used method, so the answerer knows both names exist. and helpmepls good to hear that! :)

Comment: *Method and functions are often used together"* - But they shouldn't be; *"You will find both names for the same things"* - Hmmm, technically, I would argue that they are not, a method acts on an object, a function executes, well, functionality, ones OO, ones procedural. You don't have a method in a procedural language.  The intermixing of the term is laziness on the part of developers.  Get into a language like C++  or Objective-C and you'd be confusing people.  Are we talking about a function or a object method?? They have different meanings ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Alright there you have a very good point. i will change it! :) EDIT: i changed it, but still i mentioned that they are called functions sometimes. Especially in 'java-land' it is called a function a lot...

Comment: @RobbinVoortman And as I said, that's laziness on the part of the developer ;) - You have to remember that the meaning of communication is the interruption of the receiver, you might "mean" "method", but that idea that forms in the head of those people who are listing to you, could be different ;)